# Monotouch.Dialog not sizing cells appropriately with StyledMultilineElement?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, monotouch.dialog

I'm using Xamarin and Monotouch.Dialog to show some text comments in a `UIPopoverControl`. If the text being shown in a `StyledMultilineElement` is of any great length then the Caption and the text is being shown further down (see image below). This problem gets worse if your text string is *really big*, say about 20,000 characters, because you get a huge scrolling cell with no text in it at all. Simplified version of the code I'm using in my `UITapGestureRecognizer` below.

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there a workaround?

I did have a look at the source of the `StyledMultilineElement` [here](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements.cs#L934) and am not sure if the issue is with UITableView.StringSize method.

- Any known issues with UITableView.StringSize?

Thanks,

Gavin

[image: StyledMultilineElement showing gap with large text value]

Sample code:

```
RootElement root = new RootElement("Title") { UnevenRows = true };
var section = new Section("Section Heading");
// Get a value string that is approx 1,000 chars long
var value = GetLongString();

var element = new StyledMultilineElement("Caption", value, UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle)
{
    LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
    Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue", 16f),
    SubtitleFont = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue", 16f)
};
section.Add(element);
root.Add(new List<Section>() { section });

var viewController = new DialogViewController(root);
var navbarController = new UINavigationController(viewController);

_contactPopup = new UIPopoverController(navbarController);
_contactPopup.PresentFromRect(cell.Bounds, cell, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
```

**Edit:**
Found the issues page on git hub and added issue there too [Git Hub Issue #225](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/issues/225)

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue?.